# flashing firefox os v1.2 fails for Zte Open

Tags: firefox-os

I am trying to build v1.2 of firefox os for my zte-open. With a few hiccups I was a able to configure and build it using the `inari` device profile. But the process fails at the last stage of flashing.

here is the output of the `./flash.sh` command

```
   rog% sudo ./flash.sh 
   [sudo] password for abhiram: 
   < waiting for device >
   erasing 'cache'...
   OKAY [  0.531s]
   finished. total time: 0.531s
   erasing 'userdata'...
   OKAY [  1.399s]
   finished. total time: 1.399s
   sending 'userdata' (53571 KB)...
   OKAY [  4.518s]
   writing 'userdata'...
   FAILED (status read failed (No such device))
   finished. total time: 9.911s
```

After that the device starts fresh with no userdata (obviously). Right now I am guessing that if it passes the user-data phase  it might flash the system and boot partitions.

Btw, my phone running the version 1.1 of the firmware, which was from an official Zte update.

### update

I tried flashing separate partitions of (system and boot) but the it gives me the same error.
with `./flash.sh system`

```
  FAILED (status read failed (No such device))
```

Answer (score 1):

After emailing the b2g-dev mailing list, I figured out that this was a problem with the firmware of the zte-open.

AFAIK, the latest firmware update to 1.1 brings all the devices to OPEN_US_DEV_FFOS_V1.10B01 firmware, which for some reason comes with fast-boot disabled. Hence it is not possible to flash it.

It looks like zte are working to bring out a new update that comes with fastboot enabled. So I guess I'll have to just wait it out.

#### Update

It took me a while to figure out how to update the damn phone, to upgrade you need to downgrade to the firmware 1.0B02 on which fastboot seems to work.

To downgrade I had to install clockworkmod as the default recovery program complains of signature mismatch( Zte! can't I donwngrade to your older official firmware?).

Rooting and installing clockworkmod, I had to remove some `assert` checks on the device-name from the updater-script and then pack it. Once this is done downgrading the device is quite simple.

After this I had to individually flash the three images (boot,system,userdata) using `fastboot flash` command

Answer (score 1):

I have this same problem. However I do not think that fastboot is disabled.. I say that because I can see ROAMER2 if I do a

```
fastboot devices
```

Please note.. if you cannot preform that command try running the following command first

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

after this I bet you will be able to see the devices using the fastboot command.

So fastboot seems to be able to connect to the device and the fastboot command erasing cache seemed to have worked, and the fastboot command erasing userdata command worked. So my guess is that it is not fastboot itself but the device preventing the push from occurring.

Perhaps there is a log we can read somewhere?

Update:
I called the company. Their official line is that they do not support updating the phone and you should only use the Update feature on the phone itself. There is an update coming however it is being pushed out one a time not a global push to all devices. In some blogs on this subject I saw users complain that the device is advertised as open but is not in fact open. Point being this: If the device is preventing the push as I suspect (then we as a consumer have been tricked) and the device is operating correctly.

Update: (more info)
There is a set of problems and it depends on if you upgraded your phone or not. If you read the discussion here I think it pretty much covers everything: http://www.reddit.com/r/FireFoxOS/comments/1ugx5g/firefoxos_buils_for_zte_open/

Also check to see if your device is rooted by the following

```
adb shell
```

if you see $ continue to the next command, if you see # you have root

```
su
```

If you are in the same boat as me, and have updated to 1.1 using the ZTE images. Then you are a little stuck. We need to downgrade back to  1.0 revision 2 (B02). This will require the clockwork mod recovery to do this. The problem is that we also need the original img. ZTE has taken this image down. If you have this image or if you can find it please upload it and post it here and in the link I provided (you'll be a hero to a very small group of nerds). Otherwise.. a Mozilla developer stated that ZTE will have yet another update coming soon. (However chances are this is going to be yet another locked down version). So the hunt in on for the original image.

Comment: thanks for your reply, who would have thought upgrading to that wretched 1.1 update would be this bad. Btw, if the phone is rooted and is running 1.1 is it possible to push the clockworkmod recovery image into it?

Comment: looks like you are the  hero, may be not yet.
Someone posted a media-fire link to the old zte update on the very reddit page that you mentioned in your post. I will let you if there is any news.
thanks!!

Comment: It says verification failure :(, so much for my wishful thinking.

Comment: Yes, you can put CWM on the device. I've done it, if you need the directions I can dig them up. The the image from reddit gives a Status error 7. No worries this is easily fixed (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VS8Io18Iv2s). This removes a check which stops people from doing something stupid. The check makes sure that ROAMER2 is the device name (and it is so not sure why it failed but I suspect it was a capitalization thing). Using this modified file and CWM I successfully downgraded back to 1.0. (After this I compiled from source and ./flash.sh'ed but encounted a different error.

Comment: One tiny concern, the script-kiddy in that video just searched for the first semi colon and deleted everything before that. That was really stupid, he's lucky that it worked. Instead: 1) open the file with a program that can correctly read the newline characters 2) delete the entire assert statement(s).

Comment: I got the CWM image all right and after tweaking the zip file and removing the device identification checks, I couldn't get past the flashing screen. The wierd thing was it went back to the stock recovery. I am not sure what went wrong.

Comment: btw, the writeup in the reddit page mentions that for some reason running the flash.sh script fails for the open. Pushing the invidual images (boot,user and system) seems to work. Have your tried that? Let me know.

Comment: Ahh sweet, thanks that may have fixed my problem.. (will report later) If your not getting past the flash screen I wonder if you are preforming the install correctly. In CWM you go to restore and then restore from SD card then select the zip file. But if you are back to the stock image then you might be set anyway.

Comment: looks like owe you a beer mate! :)